# How can the availability of SetFile and GetFileInfo be detected without causing user interaction? Where are Commandline Developer Tools installed?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, xcode

In bash, to detect whether a command COMMAND is available, the following statement shall be executed.  (Note that I configured bash to be the default shell, instead of zsh.)

```
type COMMAND...
```

For example, `type` detects that the command `cp` is available and that the command `foo` is unavailable.

```
$ type cp
cp is /bin/cp

$ type foo
-bash: type: foo: not found
```

Note that you can pass two or more commands to `type`.

```
$ type cp foo
cp is /bin/cp
-bash: type: foo: not found
```

However, `type` is useless to detect the genuine availability of commands `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo`, that is, to detect whether `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo` are truly usable.

`SetFile` and `GetFileInfo` belong to Commandline Developer Tools for Xcode.  macOS 12 Monterey does not automatically come with Xcode nor Commandline Developer Tools.  Hence, `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo` are supposed to be unavailable if neither Xcode nor Commandline Developer Tools is installed.  Thus, I expected `type SetFile GetFileInfo` to deny their availability.  On the contrary, `type` affirmed their availability.

```
$ type SetFile GetFileInfo
SetFile is /usr/bin/SetFile
GetFileInfo is /usr/bin/GetFileInfo
```

Then, I executed `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo` in Terminal.  However, macOS complained that `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo` were unusable.

```
The "SetFile" command requires the command line developer tools.
Would you like to install the tools now?

The "GetFileInfo" command requires the command line developer tools.
Would you like to install the tools now?
```

These error messages were not displayed in Terminal; but a GUI dialog box popped up in the desktop outside Terminal, asking the user to click either the "Install" or "Cancel" button.

**How can the genuine availability of `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo` be tested quietly without causing any user interaction?**

Let me ask some more questions related to this above question.  On one occasion, I clicked the "Install" button to let the Commandline Developer Tools (CLDT) be installed.  I thought that the Commandline Developer Tools (CLDT) would be installed into "/Applications/Xcode.app".  However, the installation of CLDT neither created the directory "/Applications/Xcode.app" nor installed CLDT into it.  Where was CLDT installed to?

Comparing before and after the installation of CLDT, has the binary file "/usr/bin/SetFile" changed?

I speculated that "/usr/bin/SetFile" depended on a library or framework from CLDT.  If this is the case, where is the CLDT library or framework?

Comment: Using `type`, or `which`, or `whence` correctly indicates that there is a command there named `SetFile`.  You want the OS to tell you whether it is the one you want, a different definition of "correct".  That's not something the OS can know.

Comment: Also, nowhere does anything say that binaries named `SetFile` and/or `GetFile` are not supposed to be available just because the CLT is not installed.  Like other parts of the system, shims are provided to install missing/wanted tools.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if the CLT is installed, one method is to look for the receipt with `pkgutil`:

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.{CLTools_Executables,CLTools_Base,DeveloperToolsCLI,DeveloperToolsCLILeo} 2>/dev/null | sed -n 's/^version: //p'
```

Which will return either null, or the version that is installed, as shown here.

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.{CLTools_Executables,CLTools_Base,DeveloperToolsCLI,DeveloperToolsCLILeo} 2>/dev/null | sed -n 's/^version: //p'
13.4.0.0.1.1651278267
$
```

If you want to know the path to which the CLT is installed, use xcode-select(1).

```
$ xcode-select -p      
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```